# WFS layer only returns a limited number of features regardless of map extent (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, wfs

After adding a WFS layer to a QGIS project, only a limited number of features are returned even after changing the extent of the map.

I want to return only features within the current extent of the map. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check `Only request features overlapping the view extent` in the `WFS / OGC API - Features` tab.

[image]